# How to run resource intensive tasks with Airflow

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, airflow

We have a long running (3h) model training task which runs every 3 days and smaller prediction pipelines that run daily.
For both cases we use Jenkins + EC2 plugin to spin up large instances(workers) and run pipelines on them. This serves 2 purposes:

1. Keep pipelines isolated. So every pipeline has all resources of one instance.
2. We save costs. Large instance run only for several hours and not 24/7

With Jenkins + EC2 plugin I am not responsible for copying code to worker and reporting the result of the execution back. Jenkins does it under the hood.

Are there anyways to achieve the same behaviour with Airflow?

Answer (score 1):

Airflow 1.10 released a host of new AWS integrations that gives you a few options for doing something like this on AWS.

https://airflow.apache.org/integration.html#aws-amazon-web-services

If you are running your task in a containerized setting, it sounds like the ECSOperator or the KubernetesPodOperator could be what you need (if you're using Kubernetes).

Comment: I guess aws batch may be even a better choice here. In both cases I will need to dockerize the code first, which also implies a more complex deployment process.